How can I backup all my files on OneDrive but keep the current availability status?
I like to backup all my files on my OneDrive to a local (external) hard disk.
Looking at my OneDrive folders I see that now some files and folders are available offline, and others are only in the cloud.
If I would download all files from OneDrive to a local disk, then all files would be permanently also on my local C drive (OneDrive folder).
Best case I would like to have the possibility to automatically download all files from my OneDrive to a local external disk, and then, maybe directly or a day later or so, the previous status of the files should be restored. Files which were only in the cloud should be only in the cloud and files which were available offline should be available offline.
I searched the internet and Windows and I didn't find any solution how to do this.
Worst case I have to do it manually, but I like to avoid that.
Is there any easy way to backup all OneDrive files without changing the status?

Maybe using an “online” client like rclone (somewhat like an FTP client) could be for you. Never tried it myself though.
